# Binding keys to JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, calculator, key-bindings

I have a fairly simple Calculator and I am trying to bind keys to JButtons. I am new to Java and I don't know much. I do know it involves ActionListener but I can't wrap my head around how to get it into what I currently have.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Calculator2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    // Declare the GUI objects and variables HERE
    JTextField ansText;
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b0, plus, minus, multi, div,
            equal, clear;
    JPanel p1, p2, p3;
    Double val1 = 0.0, val2 = 0.0, answer = 0.0;
    int operator = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calculator2();
    }

    public Calculator2() {

        // GUI Creation Code goes HERE

        ansText = new JTextField("", 7);
        ansText.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);


        ansText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { //Allow only numbers in ansText
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (((c < '0') || (c > '9')) && (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        b1 = new JButton("1");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2 = new JButton("2");
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b4.addActionListener(this);
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6 = new JButton("6");
        b6.addActionListener(this);
        b7 = new JButton("7");
        b7.addActionListener(this);
        b8 = new JButton("8");
        b8.addActionListener(this);
        b9 = new JButton("9");
        b9.addActionListener(this);
        b0 = new JButton("0");
        b0.addActionListener(this);
        plus = new JButton("+");
        plus.addActionListener(this);
        minus = new JButton("-");
        minus.addActionListener(this);
        multi = new JButton("*");
        multi.addActionListener(this);
        div = new JButton("/");
        div.addActionListener(this);
        equal = new JButton("=");
        equal.addActionListener(this);
        clear = new JButton("C");
        clear.addActionListener(this);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        p1 = new JPanel();
        this.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        p1.add(ansText);

        p2 = new JPanel();
        this.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 2, 2));
        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        p2.add(b3);
        p2.add(plus);

        p2.add(b4);
        p2.add(b5);
        p2.add(b6);
        p2.add(minus);

        p2.add(b7);
        p2.add(b8);
        p2.add(b9);
        p2.add(multi);

        p2.add(clear);
        p2.add(b0);
        p2.add(equal);
        p2.add(div);

        this.setSize(200, 250);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Number input
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b1.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b2.getText());
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b3.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b4) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b4.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b5) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b5.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b6) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b6.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b7) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b7.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b8) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b8.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b9) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b9.getText());
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == b0) {
            ansText.setText(ansText.getText() + b0.getText());
        }

        //Operator input
        else if (e.getSource() == plus) {
            operator = 1;
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(ansText.getText());
            ansText.setText("");
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == minus) {
            operator = 2;
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(ansText.getText());
            ansText.setText("");
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == multi) {
            operator = 3;
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(ansText.getText());
            ansText.setText("");
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == div) {
            operator = 4;
            val1 = Double.parseDouble(ansText.getText());
            ansText.setText("");
        } 
        //Misc
        else if (e.getSource() == equal) {
            val2 = Double.parseDouble(ansText.getText());
            if (operator == 1) {
                answer = val1 + val2;
                ansText.setText("" + answer);
            } else if (operator == 2) {
                answer = val1 - val2;
                ansText.setText("" + answer);
            } else if (operator == 3) {
                answer = val1 * val2;
                ansText.setText("" + answer);
            } else if (operator == 4) {
                answer = val1 / val2;
                ansText.setText("" + answer);
            }
        } 
        else if (e.getSource() == clear) {
            ansText.setText("");
            val1 = 0.0;
            val2 = 0.0;
            answer = 0.0;
            operator = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you see?  What is the problem?

Comment: if your trying to bind keys to buttons, i.e. pressing "+" on the keyboard is the same as clicking "+" on the GUI, check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Answer (score 2):

[How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) tutorial describes details of key bindings. Here is a simple example how to bind an action to a plus key both on the keypad and main keyboard:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD, 0), "plus");
panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS,
                InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK), "plus");

panel.getActionMap().put("plus", plusAction);
panel.add(button);
```

Comment: you forgot to mentioned abstraction a focus Xxx.getInputMap(                       JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT/*.WHEN_FOCUSED*/)
                        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("0"), "zero");

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to have a single class with a few inner classes doing all your work. Java Swing, like most other GUI systems, is based on MVC, Model-View-Controller.

The Model here would be some object that contains the current value of the accumulator and the value being stored in the display. Were you writing a RPN calculator, the model object would contain the RPN stack.

The View would be the Swing classes: the `JTextField`, and the `JButtons`.

The Controller would be some new object, say `CalculatorController`, that does the actual work.  Instead of your `ActionListener` adding, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing the numbers, they would call methods on your `CalculatorController`, and that object, in turn, would update the JTextField.

The suggestion by jedyobidan to look at Oracle's documentation is very good.  You'd want to put the key strokes into the input map of the `JPanel` itself since they should apply no matter where in the panel the user has focused upon. The action maps would then hold `AbstractActions` that call methods on the `CalculatorController`.

I've always thought that the style of GUI development on the Mac or its predecessor NeXT, with their Interface Builder programs, is much better for novices than the style used by Java Swing.